# Iterating list with given index list in python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list `A = [-1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, -3, 4, 3, 0, -1]` and `B = [0, 7, 11]`. List `B` shows the index of negative integer number index.

How can I return the sum of each slice of the list: For example sum of `A[0+1:7]` and `A[7+1:11]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), you can convert `[0, 7, 11]` to the desired slice index pairs (`1:7` / `8:11`):

```
>>> zip(B, B[1:])  # In Python 3.x, this will return an iterator.
[(0, 7), (7, 11)]
>>> [(i+1, j) for i, j in zip(B, B[1:])]
[(1, 7), (8, 11)]
```

---

```
>>> [A[i+1:j] for i, j in zip(B, B[1:])]
[[2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1], [4, 3, 0]]
>>> [sum(A[i+1:j]) for i, j in zip(B, B[1:])]
[8, 7]
```

**UPDATE**

Another way to accomplish what you want without defining `B` using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> A = [-8, 3, 0, 5, -3, 12]
>>> import itertools
>>> [sum(grp) for positive, grp in itertools.groupby(A, lambda x: x >= 0) if positive]
[8, 12]
```

`key` function was used to split *0 and positive numbers* and *negative* numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works but in case A = [-8, 3, 0, 5, -3, 12] and B = [0,4] it doesn't return 12?

Comment: @KevinOelen, `A[0+1:4] == [3, 0, 5]`.

Comment: @KevinOelen, If you want to get `[12]`, you need to specify `B = [4, 6]` or `B = [0, 4, 6]`.

Comment: @KevinOelen, Run this before running the code in the answer to handle such case: `if B[-1] < len(A): B.append(len(A))`

Comment: @KevinOelen, I updated the answer to include other version that does not require you to define `B` (indices of negative numbers) yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement like using one line list comprehension.

```
[sum(A[i+1:B[B.index(i)+1]]) if i != B[-1] else sum(A[i+1:-1]) for i in B]
```

**Result**

```
[8, 7, 0]
```

If you don't want last slice sum use this.

```
[sum(A[i+1:B[B.index(i)+1]]) for i in B if i != B[-1]]
```

**Result**

```
[8, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you see above comment and answer for that?

Comment: It should return 12 since there is a positive integer after -3

Comment: `A[0+1:4] = [3, 0, 5]` ? Right ?